# Getting layer IDs using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.3, layers

I am working in an ArcMap session, I've checked the option to get an ID for each of the layers in my document, so anyone has it.

[image]

Now, what I need is a way to get these values within a python script (to copy that automatically in a table): there's no such information in the layer's properties reached by a describe, nor from the .mapping module.

Comment: The property `DSID` in `arcpy.describe` returns the ID of the data set.  have you tried that? An example would be `desc = arcpy.Describe("some layer")` then `desc.DSID`

Comment: What version of ArcGIS are you using?

Comment: Hy Dan, the problem is that I need the ID of a layer, which doesn't seem to have the property "ID" accessible from with the describe function..

Comment: I'm working with a 10.3.1 advanced version.

Comment: What is the data source of this particular layer?  Where did you check "the option to get an ID for each of the layers"?

Comment: It's not about a particular layer or feature class, but something general. To turn on the ids check the option ("Allow assignment [...]") in the data frame's general tab.

Answer (score 4):

In ArcGIS Pro you can do this:

```py
cim_version = 'V2'
aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject(aprx_file)
map0 = aprx.listMaps()[0]
lyr0 = map0.listLayers()[0]
def0 = lyr0.getDefinition(cim_version)
# serviceLayerID will be -1 if "allow assign. unique ids to layers"
# was not check on the Data Frame properties
# in that case, serviceLayerID are in order from 0 -> len(layers) - 1
# & includes GroupLayers (can check lyr0.isGroupLayer, etc)
serviceLayerID = def0.serviceLayerID
```

Answer (score 1):

After testing this in ArcGIS 10.3, and according to the documentation available for Layer and Describe in arcpy, and also this thread: https://geonet.esri.com/thread/178341, this functionality does not yet exist.  You cannot access the layer ID from arcpy.  You may be able to access it through ArcObjects if you have the knowledge.

As a workaround, can you enter the ID into the Credits or Description fields?  You can access both of these fields through arcpy.

Comment: Goodmorning Jbalk, as you said I've written the Id layer in a table's field by using the Field Calculator tool (manually checking each layers' value). Thanks a lot for the advice, ArcObjects are my next stop..